# Using a different data field as an output

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have 3 different tables.

- Table1 logs of how many times a report has been opened with ReportID
- Table2 has CreatedID and ItemID which = ReportID
- Table3 has CreatedID, UserID, Username

I'm trying to create a report that shows who created each report with their Username. How would I do that? Here's what I have so far and its working perfect, except I want to add who created the report.

```
SELECT
COUNT(ReportID) COUNT,
Name
--CONVERT(DATE, TimeStart) StartDate


FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON b.ItemID = ReportID
WHERE TYPE IN('2','13') AND TimeStart >= @Days  AND PATH NOT LIKE '/DEVELOPEMENT%'

GROUP BY
NAME
--CONVERT(DATE, TimeStart)
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: There's not a UserID in Table 2? Seems like they should JOIN on the User not the Creator.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be as simple as joining table3. But you haven't provided sample data and you're missing a few details. Is table3 a one-to-one with table 2? If so, this should work:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(ReportID) COUNT,
    Name
    --CONVERT(DATE, TimeStart) StartDate
    , c.Username as CreatedBy

FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 b 
        ON b.ItemID = ReportID
    LEFT JOIN table3 c
        ON c.CreatedID = b.CreatedID
WHERE TYPE IN('2','13') AND TimeStart >= @Days  AND PATH NOT LIKE '/DEVELOPEMENT%'

GROUP BY
    NAME
    , t3.Username
--CONVERT(DATE, TimeStart)
```